# Is it possible 32bit data transfer using pymodbus and saving the data value in sql server?

Tags: python, pymodbus

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pymodbus.server.asynchronous import StartTcpServer
from pymodbus.device import ModbusDeviceIdentification
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSequentialDataBlock
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext
from pymodbus.datastore.database import SqlSlaveContext
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer, ModbusAsciiFramer
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
class CustomDataBlock( ModbusSequentialDataBlock):
""" A datablock that stores the new value in memory
and performs a custom action after it has been stored.
"""

def setValues(self, address, value):
    """ Sets the requested values of the datastore
    :param address: The starting address
    :param values: The new values to be set
    """
    super( ModbusSequentialDataBlock, self).setValues(address, value)
    print("wrote {} to {}".format(value, address))
    def run_custom_db_server():
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------- # 
# initialize your data store
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------- # 
block  = CustomDataBlock(0,[0]*100)
store  = SqlSlaveContext(di=block, co=block, hr=block, ir=block)
context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# initialize the server information
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------- #

identity = ModbusDeviceIdentification()
identity.VendorName = 'pymodbus'
identity.ProductCode = 'PM'
identity.VendorUrl = 'http://github.com/bashwork/pymodbus/'
identity.ProductName = 'pymodbus Server'
identity.ModelName = 'pymodbus Server'
identity.MajorMinorRevision = '2.2.0'

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# run the server you want
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------- #

# p = Process(target=device_writer, args=(queue,))
# p.start()
StartTcpServer(context, identity=identity, address=("192.168.1.12", 502))
if __name__ == "__main__":
run_custom_db_server()
```

I am sending command from modscan32 client to store 32bit unsigned integer in the pymodbus database. But it shows different value than the value I send from the modscan client. here is attached screenshot from modscan, pymodbus database and source code is also here.
[Modscan32 view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9D8B.png)

[pymodbusdb view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9L9B2.png)

Comment: A 32 bit needs to be stored on two Modbus registers, just read them from the slave with pymodbus and send them to the SQL server with any Python SQL client. Where is the problem?

Comment: @Marcos G Thanks. I am trying to send 32bit value from Modscan32 client and saving it to the sqlite3 db. In that case I am using sqlslave context and custom data block from pymodbus. for example I am Sending 150000 value to  pymodbus.db but it stores 18928 in first register and 2 stored in 2nd register of pymodbus.db.

Comment: you're welcome Tanjim, it would help if you post code on your question and explain what is going wrong. To be honest, I don't think what you're doing makes sense, Modbus registers are 16 bit, Modscan is just displaying two registers as a long integer; if you change the display options to integer you should see both registers, that should make it easier to debug. Both registers should have the same values as in Modscan. You're probably not reading the right register numbers, note that register 40001 in Modscan is register 0 in pymodbus...

Comment: @MarcosG. I edited my post. Could you please check?

Comment: @MarcosG. Could you please tell me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: I did not have time yesterday, I will take a look today

Comment: @MarcosG. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Is it possible that you are seeing outdated values? With your code, nothing is written in the database (on my tests). Can you delete the database and try again?

Comment: Yes. Maybe I have got something from here. I will write here later.Thanks

Comment: @MarcosG.everything was right. I was unable to calculate the decimal value from saved two consecutive registers of the database. apology for late writing in here.